# How to get Windows 7 Custom OEM wallpaper to appear on multiple monitors?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, login, lock-screen

I am already aware of [how to set a custom logon background on Windows 7](http://www.howtogeek.com/112110/how-to-set-a-custom-logon-screen-background-on-windows-7/). I am also not trying to tile my plain wallpaper on my desktop. I am talking about the background on the logon/lock screen in Windows 7.

What happens is on machines that have multiple monitors with custom logon screens only the main monitor that has the logon screen will display a custom oem background - every other monitor is black and I think that is gross. The blacked out monitor screens still display the cursor but do not have a background on them.

Is there any tweak to make this happen or is this truly a limitation of Windows 7?

Comment: This behavior is normal. Only the primary screen shows the lock screen even in a default setup.

Comment: Right. I don't want to move the lock screen, just the wallpaper. Either to stretch or tile it somehow would be nice.

Comment: I know what you want and I have never seen it.  My research indicates its not possible.  My experience tells me that its because of the way Windows treats the monitor until you logged into a user account.

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate for now, and refunded the bounty. If for any reason this does not cover your question, please edit it and explain why, then flag for attention to have it reopened. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is truly a limitation of Windows 7, introduced in Vista - it used to work in XP.

Even the [DisplayFusion developers say](http://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/login-in-on-secondary-monitor/?ID=b7ead4c6-9d9d-45a7-8d2e-f81d4bc39b2c) :

> The Windows 7 logon screen has no dual-monitor capability whatsoever,
>   so we can't even develop a custom solution for it.

Your only option for screen lock (not logon) is a product such as the
[Clear lock](http://techdunes.com/2011/02/02/lock-your-pc-with-clear-lock-freeware/) freeware.